# Python's (version 2.7.2) Idle does not execute any commands (command prompt works fine!!)

Tags: python, startup, python-idle

I'm trying to run python (version 2.7.2) on my computer (windows vista 32bit). It's always worked until now when Idle just does not respond to any commands.

- Any commands entered (even very simple ones) have no output/do not get computed! See image: [image]
- Python works fine when I run it using command line though!
- I've tried re-installing it a few times but it just doesn't help! Also tried running it from `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py` and I get the following message before the same unresponsive IDLE pops up again! See image:[image]

  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

  Thanks

Comment: You say IDLE is under `C:\Python27` but the screenshot above shows that you are running python from `C:\Python272`.  Is the location of IDLE correct, and if so, how many Python installations do you have?

Comment: that doesn't make a difference! I just tried that to see if it changed anything

Comment: also i installed python using the msi executable

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print 1+2
```

You need to do something with the result.

Comment: Still doesn't work! Tried creating a string "hello world!" nothing gets executed!

Comment: What did you do this the string? What are the commands you ran?

Comment: See image: dl.dropbox.com/u/32209936/image%20python%20command%20line.jpg

Comment: I tired the same on IDLE but they just wont run

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- IDLE starts a subprocess and connects to it over TCP port 8833.  Is this port being blocked by a firewall on your computer?
- Are there any files whose name clash with built-in Python modules?  [This page](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/131109/idle-giving-subprocess-error) mentions problems with files called `string.py`.
- Is the file `config-keys.def` under `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib` missing or does it have its permissions set so that nobody can read it?  I found that if I removed this file or restricted the permissions on it, IDLE became unresponsive as you described.  If I then replaced it or reset the permissions, IDLE started working again.  (Other `config-*.def` files in this folder might also need to be checked.)

Comment: That's an interesting problem! Not the case here unfortunately.. Checked and everything seems fine! The same commands and everything works fine on the command prompt. See image:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32209936/image%20python%20command%20line.jpg

Comment: OK, so the second suggestion doesn't fix things for you, but what about the first?  Is there a problem with a firewall blocking local network traffic on TCP port 8833?  The command-line Python interpreter doesn't need to use a local network connection, so perhaps that's why the command-line is working but IDLE isn't.

Comment: I turned my firewall completely off but I'm still getting the same problem! How can I check whether port 8833 is open and running or not?

Comment: @user1291006: open an administrator command prompt, run `netstat -ab` and see what program is listed against TCP 127.0.0.1:8833.  I get `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: The port you mentioned is not listed! When I run netstat -ab

Is there anything I can do now! Also in the mean while I've disabled my antivirus and firewall! Still don't find the port listed

Comment: @user1291006: the port should only be open when IDLE is running.  Besides, I'm not so sure that it's what is causing your problem.  See the suggestion I've added to my answer.

Comment: Checked the permissions and they seem fine! also tried removing and replacing them again to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the bug described here: http://bugs.python.org/issue14409

Your config file for key bindings is corrupt. Try renaming your ~/.idlerc folder to something else and restart IDLE.